# V$parameter is different in different sessions

Tags: oracle, unix, database-administration, plsqldeveloper

I connect to an oracle db through plsqldeveloper. The db can be connected via unixbox as well .Its a non-cdb oracle db of version 19.

Recently i connected to the db from unix &  changed the nls_date_format & nls_timestamp_format & bounced the db.

But when i relogin to the db from plsqldeveloper still my old format is shown. But while connecting to unix the right format is shown  Im checking the parameter values from v$parameter.

If i alter session the parameters in one session of plsqldeveloper, the new format is shown correctly, but in another session old format is shown.
Why is the difference & How to sync both the values ?

Comment: GUI tools like SQLDeveloper, TOAD, ...  have a parameter where you specify the session parameters you want to use by default. For SQL*PLUS, you can look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_two.htm#SQPUG012

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my question is how come quering v$parameter from plsqldeveloper & unix/sql evn produce different result? i have to extract certain tables with specific date format from pl/sql developer. But that format is not reflected there.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-PARAMETER.html) (emphasis added): "V$PARAMETER displays information about the initialization parameters that are **currently in effect for the session**. A new session inherits parameter values from the instance-wide values displayed by the V$SYSTEM_PARAMETER view." So if your sessions have different settings, that view *should* reflect that,

Comment: And since YOU can change the settings AND the tools you are using are running a (DIFFERENT) script at startup also setting defaults...

Comment: Understood. Is there any way i can sync both the tables value ?

Comment: Changing NLS_ parameters at the system level can have implications for backup and recovery commands or other operations that use them; it is possible to break some things if you're not careful. If you really want your sessions to be the same and not match the system default, then you will probably need to execute a logon script to set them at the session level for your specific needs. Many client tools can be configured to run logon scripts automatically. I have also found that it is often best to set format explicitly in my queries and not rely on session parameters that may change.